# I'm trying to open a particular whatsapp group through my app using intents, but unfortunately the app crashes everytime

Tags: android, android-intentservice

This is my code to perform the same function.

```
private void sendGroupMessage(String string) {

        String shareBody = string;

        
        String groupChatId = "J30MeqEdBJl1a3fQYsJVmB";

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        // Construct the group chat URI
        String groupChatUri = "https://chat.whatsapp.com/" + groupChatId;
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(groupChatUri));

        // Check if WhatsApp is installed
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please install WhatsApp first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Start WhatsApp with the specified group chat
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Here's my logcat, which says there is no app present to perform this activity.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.opshiva, PID: 25752
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND flg=0x1 pkg=com.whatsapp clip={null {T(19)}} (has extras) }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2187)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1831)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5580)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:780)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5533)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:761)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6036)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6003)
at com.example.opshiva.MainActivity.sendGroupMessage(MainActivity.java:361)
at com.example.opshiva.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:32)
at com.example.opshiva.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:151)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7570)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1218)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7540)
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29710)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8423)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)

Please tell me where am i going wrong.